# Cant update data in table

Tags: php, mysql

hi im creating a login page where it would insert data into a php table but it does not seem to insert data   into the  table   i have  2 tables in 1 database 
hrms

```
 <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$dbpassword="";
$dbname = "hrms";
$username=$_POST['username'];   
$passphrase=$_POST['passphrase'];

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $user, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND passphrase='$passphrase'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       $sql = "INSERT INTO access (user, status)
VALUES ('John', 'locked')";
    header("location: main.php");
     } else {
    header("location: index.php");
 }
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You for got to execute the insert query. Also code is open to **sql injection**.

Comment: refer this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm

Answer (score 2):

You **forgot to execute the query**, do like below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO access (user, status) VALUES ('John', 'locked')";
$conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct answer @MichaelDelaCruz . And, if you don't know how to mark answer as correct answer. Then please have a look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work